# How do I run the file through a shell command in vim for a certain filtype

Tags: filtering, vim, silent

I now have a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019317/how-to-get-a-flat-xml-so-that-external-entities-are-merged-to-the-top-level), which leads me to the next question: how do I run "xmllint --noent" to all .xml files when opening them in vim.

I have an example to do --decrypt on load and --encrypt on save for .gpg in my .vimrc, but it is so complicated that I cannot really figure the relevant parts. My latest attempt is:

```
autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost *.xml %!xmllint --noent - 2> /dev/null
```

which gives me :

```
<N> lines filtered
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How do I get rid of this? (i.e. do it silently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question might belong on superuser, but if you want to execute a command with no output, you can use `silent`

I.E.

```
:silent !echo Hello
```

see: [Avoiding the "Hit ENTER to continue" prompts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts)

Comment: `autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost *.xml silent %!xmllint --noent - 2> /dev/null` did the trick, Thank-you!